# Application_Error getting called numerous times

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I have application built on asp.net MVC3. Application runs fine but I see one issue here that on every page load Application_Error method is getting executed multiple times and the same time no exception is thrown so as such application never breaks.
On debugging I could see error message but I am not able to figure out why this error is coming. I would appreciate any help.

> [7/24/2011 10:30:04 PM] Error: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): File does not exist.     at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.GetFileInfo(String virtualPathWithPathInfo, String physicalPath, HttpResponse response)     at System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext context, String overrideVirtualPath)     at System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: When we had this problem I was missing a required DLL on my machine (it was something from Microsoft Enterprise Practices). Try using ProcMon to file out which file it cannot find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use tool such as fiddler or firebug (on Firefox) to check the requests issued from browser and which one is getting the 404 (file not found) - that will be culprit.

Said that the most probable cause would be the request to web site icon i.e. **`"/favicon.ico"`** - most browsers issue this request to get the fav-icon for site which is typically used in address bar, bookmarks etc to easily identify the site. Its quite likely that you don't have this file under your site/project hence it generates 404 (File Not Found) error. The web development server (or IIS in certain config) uses managed pipeline to server all requests, so every request would go via global.ajax including errors for each request. Whenever you do refresh (F5) on your site, you will get the error.

Comment: I guess you guessed my issue correctly. I've never used fiddler before but I downloaded it and it should solve my problem. Will mark it as answer once I solve it. Thanks.

Comment: @Vinay fiddler shows that there are some js files/images which are referred but doesn't exists and because of which application_error is getting called. But is there any way that I can prevent app_error fn call on such issues because my error log is getting spammed with such errors? Anyway these errors don't show up on application and user is not affected.

Comment: @Pramodtech, you can filter these errors by looking at exception type (`HttpException`) and 404 status code(`HttpException.GetHttpCode()`). However, its **important** that you should remove references to not required js/images because they are never fetched/cached and so browser will issue requests for them in every post-back. This is unnecessary load on server and on browser side, there will be slight latency due to more concurrent requests.

Comment: @Vinay I understand that we should not have references to files which do not exists and I'll remove that. I'm just curious on how these errors do not show up on front end? Also It may not be good to filter 404 errors as it may occur when user is trying to old/removed pages from app.

Comment: @Pramodtech, if you paste url to such resource in address bar, you will see the error. The errors go to frond-end as 404, but because those requests are for embedded content within document, browser may not show them (as long as document html has been received). Of course, in case of images, you can see alternate text (or generic not found icon). Regarding filtering of 404, its bad idea but that's what u have asked for. U cannot selective log 404 unless you can figure out from request path what is to be logged and what is not. I would rather log everything and remove bad references from code.