# File does not exist Exception- favicon.ico

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a `Global.asax` file that has logging code inside `Application_Error` handler. I need  to customize it in such a way that the Application_Error handler is not reached if the exception is happened while looking for a `favicon.ico` file. How can we bypass the hitting of Application_Error when the exception is for favicon.ico?

> Exception: File does not exist.

```
Url: http://localhost:14658/favicon.ico
```

Note: There is no  favicon.ico reference in the solution

Note: I am using internet explorer as the browser

**CODE**

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception occuredException = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[UIConstants.PayrollSQLConnection].ConnectionString;
        ExceptionBL exceptionBL = new ExceptionBL(connectionString);

        string location = Request.Url.ToString();

        exceptionBL.SubmitException(occuredException.Message, location);


    }
```

**Reference**:

1. [Application_Error getting called numerous times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909248/application-error-getting-called-numerous-times)

Comment: You will have to examine the result from `Server.GetLastError()`

Comment: @RichardSchneider Thanks. Can you please provide little more details regarding what are the points to check?

Comment: in case people come across this...favicon.ico is loaded by ie (and others?) automatically, looking to display an icon for the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just add **favicon.ico** on your project (IIS)

Comment: You should try to add **favicion.ico** on Root

Comment: can you explain how to add 'favicon.ico' to "Root"? I dont understand what you are saying.

Comment: just create file having name "favicion.ico" and add into your project

Answer (score 1):

If the Exception is a `FileNotFoundException` then something like

```
 var fnf = theException as FileNotFoundException;
 if (fnf && fnf.FileName == '...')
     return;
```

However, you need to post the `Exception` details before I can give specific code.

Comment: The Exception being referred to is of type System.Web.HttpException

Answer (score 1):

1) Add favicon.ico in your web.UI project. 
2) If you are using asp.net MVC. Ignore the route by adding:

```
 var routes = RouteTable.Routes;
 routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
```