# File does not exist - favicon.ico

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have split an ASP.NET website into a web application (AppCode classes is now a separate DLL).

I have a Global.asax file.  When I launch a webpage I now get an error, which says: "file does not exist"  The webpage loads successfully.

After some further analysis it appears that the web application is looking for a file called: favicon.ico.  What is this file?

I have Googled this and I can accross webpages like this: [File does not exist Exception- favicon.ico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474391/file-does-not-exist-exception-favicon-ico).  I am yet to find an answer.

It appears that the web application throws the error but the website does not.

**Update**
I created a blank website project with one webpage (default.aspx) and the Global.asax.  I then created blank web application project with one webpage (default.aspx) and the Global.asax.  Both the Global.asax files contained Application_Error sub routines.  I discovered that the error in question appeared for the web application only.  Therefore I am lead to believe that favicon.ico is required for web application projects.

Comment: What webserver are you using? IIS, Apache?

Comment: You can find detailed description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570211/error-in-global-asax-file-does-not-exist. Web application works exactly like described there, while in web site the request for static resource doesn't go through `Global.asax` (but the request is still made and it still returns 404, only the error is being handled on different level)

Comment: @tpeczek, could you post an answer so that I can give some credit?

Comment: @w0051977 You can upvote the answer I have linked and if you think that it answers your question you can just close it as duplicate. Giving an answer as a link to another answer doesn't feel quite like things suppose to work here on SO so I'm doing my best to avoid it :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

favicon.ico is a small image that will be rendered in the page tab in the browser. You can generate it using http://www.favicon.cc/

Once generated, you can place the file on the root of the website and see if the error still persists.

Comment: Please would you have a look at my update (in the OP).  Does this sound correct? +1 for the link.